# How to add a constant column to a SQL query without parsing it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a complex query supplied by other part of the application and I need to add a constant column and pass the query for further processing (SSRS ServerReport). The query can consist of several queries connected with `UNION ALL` and can contain `ORDER BY`.

**Edit:** I forget to emphasize what is included in title **without parsing.** I don't know nothing about query (conditions, subqueries) so parsing and modified it is rather dangerous.

Example:

```
declare @t table(id int)
insert into @t values(1)
insert into @t values(2)
```

The query:

```
(select  id from @t where id=1
union all
select  id from @t where id=2) order by id desc
```

Required Output:

```
id | Par
----------
2  | Hello   
1  | Hello
```

Attempt (not working with ORDER BY):

```
SELECT *, 'Hello' Par from
((select  id from @t where id=1
    union all
    select  id from @t where id=2) order by id desc) tbl
```

Solution has to work on SQL Server 2008+.

Comment: I apologize for missing opening parentheses in the Attempt query.

Comment: Thanks to all contributors. I accepted that there is no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fix this without injecting into the query (or creating verbose dynamic SQL like @satcat66's answer). The subquery with the union needs an alias to define it, e.g. `where id=2) AS alias ORDER BY id DESC)...` There is no magic that will make this broken syntax work.

Comment: I was afraid of that when I asked but I still hope.

Answer (score 1):

```
select tbl.id,
    'Hello' Par
from (
    select id
    from @t
    where id = 1

    union all

    select id
    from @t
    where id = 2
 ) tbl
order by tbl.id desc
```

I assume you are UNIONing different queries than your example, otherwise you would just do:

```
select id,      
   'Hello' Par
from @t
where id in (1, 2)
order by id desc
```

Comment: The solution includes necessity to separate ORDER BY from query. This  is what I want to avoid.

Comment: It is also syntactically incorrect - there is an extra closing paren.

Comment: Typo fixed (parenthesis removed)

Comment: @AaronBertrand By "not working" I mean that the query returns a exception. The query presents what I want to achieve, it seems to me syntactically correct but it is not accepted by server.

Comment: @IvanH what is "a exception"? Can you be more specific? What "server" are you talking about? Do you have a table variable named `@t`? The query works fine here. But it still seems to violate your requirement that you not have to put the `tbl` alias on the subquery... :-(

Comment: @AaronBertrand "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'". MS SQL 2008 R2 (SQL2008 is required in question)

Comment: Then I suspect you didn't copy the code correctly, because it works here. My guess is that either you didn't include the `tbl` alias, or the tool you used to submit the query stripped it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(id int)
insert into @t values(1)
insert into @t values(2) 

;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT id, 'Hello' Par
     FROM @t t1 WHERE t1.id=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, 'Hello' Par
    FROM @t t2 WHERE t2.id=2
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY id DESC
```

[WITH common_table_expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: The solution includes necessity to separate ORDER BY from query. This is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CTE:

```
declare @t table(id int)
insert into @t values(1)
insert into @t values(2) 
;
with my_cte as (
    select  id from @t where id=1
    union all
    select  id from @t where id=2
)
select *, 'Hello'
from my_cte
order by id
```

EDIT:
in this case you can insert the result of the main query in a temp table. It will respect the ordering:

```
create table #temptable(
id int
)

declare @t table(id int)
insert into @t values(1)
insert into @t values(2) 

insert into #temptable
select  id from @t where id=1
union all
select  id from @t where id=2
order by id desc

select *, 'Hello' from #temptable
```

result:

```
2   Hello
1   Hello
```

Comment: The solution includes necessity to separate ORDER BY from query. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: where do you want to order them?

Comment: The order by clause is part of original query, but it is not necessarily included (and I don't know included coumns.)

Comment: Yes this seems to work. But I am not sure whether the destination (MS Reporting services report) will accept it. If there is no other solution I will accept this. But probably I will not use it.

Comment: @IvanH Why do you care if reporting services will accept it? If you put the code into a stored procedure (which you should be doing always anyway), SSRS isn't going to care what happened inside the stored procedure...

Comment: @AaronBertrand The query can't be in stored procedure this is a temporary query created just for required report.

Comment: The solution with temporary table requires knowledge of fields returned by query so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

your query has a little problem

```
SELECT *, 'Hello' Par from
(select  id from @t where id=1
    union all
    select  id from @t where id=2) tbl order by id desc
```

Comment: Yes I know it. How to avoid is what I am looking for. (I have stated that query does not work).

Comment: put the alias after select ') tbl' and after 'order by id desc' , the query from my response works

Comment: and now you give me the copy paste "The solution ..." :) , put another alias if you want , describe the whole problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know column names and types in advance,

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
SET @query = '

declare @t table(id int);
insert into @t values(1);
insert into @t values(2); 
(select  id from @t where id=1
    union all
    select  id from @t where id=2) order by id desc';

 CREATE TABLE #T ( ind int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, id int );
 INSERT INTO #T (id)
 exec sp_executesql @query;

 SELECT ID, 'Hello' AS Par FROM #T ORDER BY ind;
```